# Not able to access empty dataframe which is defined outside the function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined `indicator` dataframe outside the function. I am trying to append value to the dataframe inside the function. But i am getting unresolved reference error.

Source code:

```
   indicator = pd.DataFrame()

   def chart(x):
      df   # sample dataframe 
      indicator = indicator.append(df)

   for i in range(array_length):
       chart(x)

   print(indicator)
```

> I am getting syntax error : Unresolved reference 'indicator'

Can anyone help solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing an assignment inside your function, so `indicator` is treated as a local variable and an `UnboundLocalError` is raised. Try either

1. Declaring `indicator` global
2. Pass `indicator` to your function *(recommended)*:

   ```
   def chart(df2):
     return df2.append(df)

   indicator = chart(indicator)
   ```

Note that the exception occurs on `indicator` rather than `df` because no assignment takes place on `df`, so the interpreter resolves it to be global without issue.